# Hot to use watij to click element (Java)

Tags: javascript, html, click, watij

I need watij to click the location of `sizeDropdown` code
Please help me go about doing this in java.

The HTML code:

```
<div class="size-quantity">
    <span class="sizeDropdown">
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebSpec spec = new WebSpec().ie();
    // http://jsfiddle.net/rnFm8/
    spec.open("http://fiddle.jshell.net/rnFm8/show/");

    // find <span> by innerText = "SPAN WAITING FOR CLICK"
    // spec.find.span().with("SPAN WAITING FOR CLICK").click();

    // or by CSS class using JQuery selector
    spec.jquery(".sizeDropdown").click();
}
```